# Net rate of heat transfer of venting air into another room?

Tags: heat-transfer

I have a portable air conditioner, but I don't have a window in my room. I'm only gonna be here for about 2 more weeks, but the temperature is in the 80s/90s, and I'm very sensitive to the heat that it's affecting my sleep, so I'm trying to find a temporary solution.

I'm thinking about venting the hot air into the hall way through my door. I would leave the door cracked open slightly (just enough to put the tube through), but I don't know how well this'll work, since hot air will just come in through the crack.

The door is about 8ft tall, and I would crack it open just enough to put the tube through. The tube diameter is about 6". So the door would expose about a 8ft by 6" area, about most of that area will allow hot air from outside the room to come in to my room, and a small portion, for the tube, will be getting rid of the hot air from inside my room to the outside.

Roughly, do you guys think this would result in a reduction in temperature in my room?

I'm not really concerned about efficiency as this is just a temporary solution. My room is about 80-85 F, and I would be happy if I can get that down to 70-75.

Comment: @jsotola I changed enough about the post that I don't believe this constitutes as cross posting. The diy stackexchange, as you can see, is looking for ideas on how to use a portable air conditioner. This post here, as you can see, is especially about one idea, and the heat transfer implications.

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, have you tried using a fan to increase the velocity of the air. Even at 80s or 90s, (Depending on the humidity) you can improve a lot the thermal comfort by increasing the air speed in a room.

Comment: the problem with a portable air conditioner is that the air you exhaust into the hallway has to be replaced with air, either from the hallway (likely), or from outside.  You will be cool in front of the cold air discharge; the room as a whole may or may not actually cool.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to add a cardboard, paper or fabric rectangle to the door with tape or, if your door and frame are metal, magnets. This will reduce the air transfer and improve the heat reduction of the installation.

If some form of blocking is not in place, as the unit forces the hot air into the hall, it will reduce the air pressure within the room, pulling warm air from the door opening, which is going to be the exhaust air, already heated, making things worse.

For an additional, although minor improvement, adding an elbow to the exhaust hose, to direct it to one side, will relocate the hot plume away from the open, blocked door.